# Onclick not working with button created in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, button, onclick, leaflet

I made a function that puts a button in a leaflet popup like

```
function popUp(feature, json){
    myfunc("Cat").outerHTML
};
```

Here's the function that creates the button

```
function myfunc(String) {
button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = String
button.onclick = function dog() {
    alert("dog");
    return false;
};
document.body.appendChild(button);
  return button
};
```

The button appears and is clickable in the popup but it doesn't do anything when clicked. I allowed pop-ups in Chrome and even tried it in Firefox but it still won't work.

Also, these two functions are in a functions.js file separate from my index.html file.

Comment: I just tried our your two scripts by executing `popUp();` and when I clicked on the button titled **Cat**, an alert showed with the content **dog**. Firefox 97.0 here.

Comment: Ok, I just restarted XAMPP and then my laptop but the alert still doesn't show.

Comment: Read https://css-tricks.com/choice-words-about-the-upcoming-deprecation-of-javascript-dialogs/ and consider using `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. Also, pay attention at "the browser may not display a dialog" bit at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert . Make sure the code you post actually reproduces the problem, as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: Otherwise, [works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/a7sUo3zDUvYeTHWC).

Comment: I'm trying to understand the first article. The second one, I'm not switching tabs. And I tried to use `alert()` outside the popup.

Comment: couldn't find any error. There could be one reason, that is function ordering. 
You have to declare `myFunc` before `popUp` since javascript read codes from top to bottom. @BallpenMan

Comment: @hasan05 I just tried your comment but still didn't work. `popUp` also uses other functions below it and it's working. It's just `alert()` isn't working for me. I'll have to try actual function I want for the button instead.

Comment: @BallpenMan, whenever I try to check raw js code, I just open a console and write whatever I need.  Even, just now I copied your code and paste it to console and hola it works perfectly. That means, I hope the issue is in either your working pc or your used browsers. somehow they blocks popup. you can check only `alert()` is working properly or not.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing return false from button function

```
button.onclick = function dog() {
    alert("dog");
};
```

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't help